# Errors with 'IEnumerator<T>' and 'object'

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me with this code?

```cs
public static void enqueue()
{
    using (object obj = (object)File.ReadLines(Program.combo).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while ((((IEnumerator)obj).MoveNext() ? 1U : 0U) != (uint)0)
        {
            Program.comboQueue.Enqueue(((IEnumerator<string>)obj).Current);
        }
    }
    using (object obj2 = (object)File.ReadLines(Program.proxies).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while ((((IEnumerator)obj2).MoveNext() ? 1U : 0U) != (uint)0)
        {
            Program.proxyQueue.Enqueue(((IEnumerator<string>)obj2).Current);
        }
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

**1.** Using the generic type `IEnumerator<T>` requires 1 type arguments.

**2.** `object`: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to `System.IDisposable` or implement a suitable `Dispose` method.

Comment: Both errors seems very clear to me. What is it _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out? What have you done so far to research the issue, what did you find, and why did that not solve your problem? Please improve this question. (And you should be aware, a site like this isn't here to jump when you say jump...putting imperatives like _"ASAP!"_ into your question isn't going to help your cause, and likely will be counter-productive.)

Comment: Hint: See how `File.ReadLines` is declared.

Comment: I need fix this code but im new in c# and i don't know how to fix the errors and i want someone who help me with this.

Comment: What did you program in before C#? This not to offend, but I am really curious because you are transforming boolean results to 1 and 0 and check against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
  public static void enqueue()
    {
        using (var obj = File.ReadLines(Program.combo).GetEnumerator()) // yo dont need to cast to object
        {
            while (obj.MoveNext()) // MoveNext returns bool if it can read next recod  it will bet true 
            {
                Program.comboQueue.Enqueue(obj.Current);
            }
        }
        using (var obj2 = File.ReadLines(Program.proxies).GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (obj2.MoveNext())
            {
                Program.proxyQueue.Enqueue(obj2.Current);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or use `foreach` it does the same as above.

```
  foreach (string item in File.ReadLines(Program.combo)) // yo dont need to cast to object
  {
      Program.comboQueue.Enqueue(item);
  }

  foreach (string item in File.ReadLines(Program.proxies)) // yo dont need to cast to object
  {
      Program.comboproxyQueueQueue.Enqueue(item);
  }
```

Comment: Directly calling `IEnumerator` methods is really quite unnecessary. use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As shown, your code should read:

```
public static void enqueue()
{
    using (var obj = File.ReadLines(Program.combo).GetEnumerator()) 
    {
        while (obj.MoveNext()) 
        {
            Program.comboQueue.Enqueue(obj.Current);
        }
    }
    using (var obj2 = File.ReadLines(Program.proxies).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (obj2.MoveNext())
        {
            Program.proxyQueue.Enqueue(obj2.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's worth some explanation.

`ReadLines.GetEnumerator()` returns an object of type `IEnumerator<string>`, which both has a `MoveNext()` method, and can be put in a `using` block.

By casting it to `object` you are hiding its type from the compiler, causing the errors you get, and also requiring the unnecessary cast back to `IEnumerator<string>`.

That said, your code is overly complex. The `foreach` loop is there for this sort of thing, so your code should read:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Program.combo))
    Program.comboQueue.Enqueue(line);

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Program.proxies))
    Program.proxyQueue.Enqueue(line);
```